# Using Jquery to dynamically create objects

Tags: forms, jquery-selectors, object

I'm trying to dynamically create objects out of forms, but I want some reduntant elements to be ommitted, such as the submit.

The only problem is that my function won't omit these fields.

```
    function form_to_json(formname) {

    var obj = new Object();

    var identity = "#" + formname + " input";

// Create JSON strings ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    $(identity).each(function() {

        if ($(this).val() != "Submit" || $(this).attr('name') != "password2") {

            var propertyName  = $(this).attr('name');
            var propertyValue = $(this).val();

            eval("obj." + propertyName + "='" + propertyValue + "'");               
        }
    });

    var jsonObj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    return jsonObj;
}
```

The output spits out a nice little json object the only problem is it doesn't omit the form elements I'm asking it to.

Is it something to do with the selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I just had a brainstorm and tried splitting up the if statement into two...

```
if ($(this).val() != "Submit") {

                if ($(this).attr('name') != "password2") {

                    var propertyName = $(this).attr('name');
                    var propertyValue = $(this).val();

                    eval("obj." + propertyName + "='" + propertyValue + "'");
                }           
            }
```

This did work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in single if condition also. You just have to change OR condition to AND

```
if ($(this).val() != "Submit" && $(this).attr('name') != "password2") {
```